# How to Differentiate two input images?

Tags: python, opencv

i Just want to process image. the prob;em is i have two kind of input images. One is exactly snapped the card image, the another one is snapped by keeping on table in which the credit card is at the centre of the snap. I just want to categorize the input image after getting the input and reading it. Python and OpenCV is in what i am trying to develop.

I have tried something with finding the edges, but i am looking forward something better than that step.

```
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]  

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

        if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
            break
```

I need a methodology in image processing to differentiate my scenario of input images using python and opencv

Comment: Post example images to some free hosting service and put the URLs here so we can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Look into SSIM. [Here's](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/) a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to [follow a tutorial like this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html). Basically you need to do:

- Key point extraction. You'll find a lot of stuff online about SIFT and SURF but you'll need the contrib lib for that. If you don't have contrib, I suggest BRISK, AKAZE or ORB.
- Then you can do key point matching.
- Then you filter out the bad matches either using the distance or a distance ratio test.

After this based on the number of good matches you have, you'll have a pretty good idea if the the object is in the image. If you want to go further and find the image on screen / filter out false positives you can:

- Find homography of the matches
- Check for inliners
- Transform perspective to find it on the image / scene

Best of luck!

Comment: IS it ok with finding edges and contours of the input, based on that we can classify? i.e if the input image has edges and contours its kind and if it doesn't then its other kind?

Comment: the credit card exactly snapped is one kind. Another one is kept on a4 sheet and snap the card along with a4 sheet. now i want to differentiate these two input images.

Comment: please explain more clearly I don't understand. What do you mean you want to differentiate? You want to check if it is the same of find the differences?